# Control resolution of exported chart

Tags: image, excel, export, resolution, vba

I have an excel userform which allows you to save excel charts in a certain worksheet to a .jpg image and at the same time show the chart in the userform. However I have found that it is hard to control the resolution of said image. The resolution seems te depend on the amount of zoom on the worksheet. When I zoom in, I get a high quality image and when I zoom out the resolution becomes very poor. Is there a way to control this using vba code?

The code I am using for the export is below:

```
Private Sub CmdBrowse_Click()
Dim Directory1 As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Show
  On Error Resume Next
  Directory1 = .SelectedItems(1)
  Err.Clear
  On Error GoTo 0
End With

ChartDest.Value = Directory1
End Sub

Private Sub CmdLoad_Click()
Dim FilePath As String
Dim Imagename As String
Dim ChartNumber As Integer

If ChartDest = "Select chart destination folder" Then
    MsgBox "Select chart destination"
    Exit Sub
End If

ChartNumber = ChartList.ListIndex + 1

'saving chart to image
Imagename = ChartList.Value
FilePath = ChartDest & Imagename & ".jpeg"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad3").ChartObjects(ChartNumber).Chart.Export FilePath, "jpg"
'loading image
UserForm4.ChartImage.Picture = LoadPicture(FilePath)
End Sub
```

ChartDest is a textbox with the destination path.
Chartlist is a listbox with a list of avaiable charts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your CmdLoad

```
Private Sub CmdLoad_Click()
    Dim fPath As String, imgName As String, chartID As Long

    If chartDest = "Select chart destination folder" Then
        MsgBox "Select chart destination"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    chartID = ChartList.ListIndex + 1

    'saving chart to image
    imgName = ChartList.Value
    fPath = chartDest & imgName & ".jpeg"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad3").ChartObjects(chartID)
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 175
        .Chart.Export fPath, "jpg"
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    End With

    'loading image
    UserForm4.ChartImage.Picture = LoadPicture(fPath)
End Sub
```

Comment: I opted to use the `activewindow.zoom` method because `scaleheight` and `scalewidth` are methods that work for shapes and not for charts or chartobjects. Thanks for the solution.