# How can I export excel charts in higher resolutions within python?

Tags: python, excel, charts, export, png

Currently I have found a way to export excel charts within python. However, these images are in a very low quality. This is what I have now:

```
#Importing the modules
from win32com.client import Dispatch

workdir = 'C:/Users/example/'
excel_file = 'filename.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheetname'
output_directory = workdir  + 'output/'


app = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename=excel_file)
app.DisplayAlerts = False
dpi = 300  # Set the desired resolution (dots per inch)


i = 1
for sheet in workbook.Worksheets:
    sheet.Activate()  # Activate the sheet
    for chartObject in sheet.ChartObjects():
        print(sheet.Name + ':' + chartObject.Name)
        chart = chartObject.Chart
        #chart.ChartArea.Width = chart.ChartArea.Width * dpi / 72
        #chart.ChartArea.Height = chart.ChartArea.Height * dpi / 72
        chart.Export(output_directory + str(i) + '.png', FilterName="PNG")
        i = i+1
workbook.Close(SaveChanges=False, Filename=excel_file)
app.Quit()
```

However, above pictures are thus in low quality. I tried to change the width and height, but this ruins the charts. So are for example all the text and lines getting smaller and smaller. It doesn't have to be .png. It would be fine to first save it as pdf/jpg as long as it is a high resolution picture.

Comment: If your have the original data, I think plot the chart use matplotlib or plotly will be a much more better way

Comment: [Possibly helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125021/control-resolution-of-exported-chart).

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer given in the question *BigBen* linked to, increase the `ActiveWindow.Zoom` level before exporting the chart, then reset it. Setting the zoom to 400 resulted in a nice big, crisp chart for me.

```py
#Importing the modules
from win32com.client import Dispatch

workdir = 'C:/Users/example/'
excel_file = 'filename.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheetname'
output_directory = workdir  + 'output/'


app = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename=excel_file)
app.DisplayAlerts = False
dpi = 300  # Set the desired resolution (dots per inch)


i = 1
for sheet in workbook.Worksheets:
    sheet.Activate()  # Activate the sheet
    for chartObject in sheet.ChartObjects():
        print(sheet.Name + ':' + chartObject.Name)
        chart = chartObject.Chart
        zoom = app.ActiveWindow.Zoom # Take note of the original zoom level
        app.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 400 # Bump it right up
        chart.Export(output_directory + str(i) + '.png', FilterName="PNG")
        app.ActiveWindow.Zoom = zoom # Then reset it after exporting the chart
        i = i+1
workbook.Close(SaveChanges=False, Filename=excel_file)
app.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, a bit late reaction of my part. But this indeed worked! This was indeed what I was looking for